# I got the error C2440:

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I got the following error

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int
>   [16]'

My code is like this

```
static int Count[MAX_STATION_NO] = 0;
```

I got error on above line. Can someone tell me what is the problem in the above line?

Comment: You probably wanted: `static int Count[MAX_STATION_NO] = {0}`;

Answer (score 0):

You're treating an array as a pointer, which is illegal. You can't assign an array to a value.

Perhaps you want this:

```
static int Count[MAX_STATION_NO] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array and setting the arrays value to '0'. What I think you wish to do is:

```
static int Count[MAX_STATION_NO] = {0}
```

Comment: No, he's not setting the array values to 0. His code is just illegal.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I meant was, the code implies that it is setting the value of an array to an integer, causing a datatype mismatch, and then proceeded to giving a solution based on what I assume he actually wished to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your initializer needs to be in braces:

```
static int Count[MAX_STATION_NO] = { 0 };
```

Btw: static arrays have their content initialized with 0 anyway so you the above is equivalent to:

```
static int Count[MAX_STATION_NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is declaring an array of size 16, then you are assigning a single number to it, which is not syntactically correct. You need to use an array initializer:

```
{ 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Curly brace `{}` are required to initialize arrays. 
eg:

```
static int Count[MAX_STATION_NO]={1,2,3};
```

Maybe this link could help you: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: This is C++11 systax. A lot of compilers (before VS2010) require the `=` before the initialization list.